# Error: No overload for method 'Kill' takes 1 args

Tags: c#

I have been trying to kill a process with C# in Visual Studio. I always get this error with error code *CS1501*:

> "No overload for method 'Kill' takes 1 arguments".

Here is how I tried to kill Notepad:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill("notepad.exe");
```

I have also tried `Process.Kill();` alone but it displays this error with a *CS0103* code:

[image: "The name 'Process' does not exist in the current context"]

Comment: As documented, those methods don't accept strings. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=net-6.0#overloads

Comment: You need to *find* the right instance of `Process`, then call the `Kill` method on it. I suggest you research `Process.GetProcessesByName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Process.Kill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=net-6.0) has two overloads; one that takes no arguments, and one that takes a `boolean`. You cannot pass a `string` to it because there is no implicit conversion from `string` to `boolean`.

Additionally, `Process.Kill` isn't static, so you can't call `Process.Kill()` directly, you have to call `Kill()` on an instance of [`Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-6.0).

If you want to kill another process, you'll first have to get an instance of that process, then call `Kill()` on that instance.

Perhaps the easiest way to get the instance of the target process is by using [`GetProcessesByName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?view=net-6.0) which accepts the name of the target process and returns an array of all matching, running processes (`Process[]`).

From there, you can call `Kill()` on any item in the array to stop the corresponding process. Here's an example that kills the first matching process if any are found.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

if (Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault() is Process p)
{
    p.Kill();
}
```

Note that this example uses [`FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0) from `System.Linq` which will return the first item in the array or `default(Process)` which is `null` if there are no items in the array. The case when there is an object is separated from the case when there is not by using the [`is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is) to determine if `FirstOrDefault` returned an instance of `Process` (which will be called `p` if so) or `null` (in which case the `if` block never runs).

Comment: Tell us how it works